# Pre-Checked Checkbox function

Tags: javascript, checkbox

we have on our orderform a function that allows to hide the order-button, when a user does not agree to the Terms and Conditions.

You can see it here: https://secure.purevisionmethod.com/orderforms/launch/step2.php

Right now the page comes up with the checkbox unchecked. We want to set it up, so that it's pre-checked, and that the order-button turns hiding, when a user unchecks the box.

I added checked="checked" to the  of the checkbox, but the function controlling the show-hide function doesn't see it.

This is the function:

```
<script>
$('#agree_box').change(function(){
   (this.checked)?$('#offer_fade').css('display','none'):$('#offer_fade').css('display','block');
});
</script>
```

Can you see why it's not recognizing the preselected checked="checked" within this piece of java?

Thanks!!

Comment: What's this? `(this.checked)?$('#offer_fade').css('display','none'):$('#offer_fade').css('display','block');`

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: Why do you expect that code to run?

Comment: `$('#offer_fade').toggle(this.checked);`

Comment: @MelanciaUK - I didn't get an error, just not the function to work. Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that checks the check state of the checkbox (on DOM ready), you are only attaching an event listener.  If you want to trigger the event/handler you should either use `change`, `triggerHandler` or `trigger` method.

```
//$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#agree_box').change(function() {
       $('#offer_fade').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change(); // execute the change handler(s) once on DOM ready
//});
```

Comment: I added your code to the page, and it listens to the toggling now, and I added the pre-checking of the checkbox.

But, it doesn't show the button when checked, only when unchecked.

Where am I going wrong now?

Comment: @Veit Try changing the handler's body to `$('#offer_fade').toggle(!this.checked);` then. You show the overlay when the checkbox is checked.